# Destructuring js class for access from outside constructor

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I am looking to make my code more readable, getting rid of LOADS of "this." references in js Class functions.

For some reason, this is working :

```
function OtherPerson(name, age, surname) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.surname= surname;
  this.destructure = {name:n, age:a, surname:s} = this;
  this.introduceFull = function() {
    console.log(`${this.name} ${this.surname} is ${this.age}`);
  } 
  this.introduceShort = function() {
    console.log(`${n} ${s} is ${a}`);
  } 
}

var bob = new OtherPerson("bob", 32, "smith");
bob.introduceFull();  //outputs "bob smith is 32"

var sam= new OtherPerson("sam", 33, "smith");
sam.introduceShort(); //outputs "same smith is 33"
```

Now, I am looking to achieve the same thing with a JS Class, as in following pseudocode:

```
class Person {

   constructor(name, age, surname) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.surname = surname;
      //somehow destructure data here and make it accessible from outside constructor ?
   }

   someMethod() {
      //get access to destructured data here
   }

}
```

All my attempts have resulted in failure. And I would like to avoid destructuring `this` everytime I call some methods. Hoping for the best !

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this is what you wanted to achieve. There is nothing wrong with using this to access variables.

If this isnt what you wanted, feel free to comment and I will gladly try to help you!

```js
class Person {

   constructor(name, age, surname) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.surname = surname;
      //somehow destructure data here and make it accessible from outside constructor ?
   }

   introduceFull() {
    return this.name + this.age + this.surname;
  }

}

let bob = new Person("bob", 32, "smith");
console.log(bob.introduceFull());
console.log(bob.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am aware that using `this` is perfectly okay but my classes have gotten pretty heavy and it would somehow improve the readability